# Can you modify CPU registers from within VS2008 IDE?

Tags: .net, debugging, cpu-registers

Was just wondering if there was a way to edit the CPU registers (i.e. EAX, EBX, ECX, etc) or flags (OV, UP, erc) from within the Visual Studio IDE.  I know you can **view** them using the Registers pane (ctrl-shift-G) and you can cycle through them with TAB or ENTER, but I don't seem to be able to change any of them while debugging (yes, program execution is halted :)).

I don't really have a strong need to do so, it's just that: I can see the assembly... I used to be able to do this (VC++6)... why can't I now, kind'a thing!

Thanks!

Comment: @Keith

no, that doesn't work...

from my post (you know... the one up top)

> "... you can cycle through them with TAB or ENTER, but I don't seem to be able to change any of them"

now... if you can tell me why it's not working THEN you can be cocky ;)

Comment: Believe that only works for native code, not managed code.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can....

from the help  (you know...the f1 key)

To change the value of a register

- In the Registers window, use the TAB key or the mouse to move the insertion point to the value you want to change. When you start to type, the cursor must be located in front of the value you want to overwrite.
- Type the new value.
- Press ENTER.

Comment: This only works for Native code, not managed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzztbfkk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. That awful thing doesn't work in managed mode or mixed mode.